# How do I change individual characters in a pointer string?

Tags: c, pointers, char

I can't seem to change individual characters in a pointer without the program crashing. R1 must be a pointer.

```
char * R1[6];       
int main (){
   *R1 = "33333";
   printf("%s\n", *R1);
   R1[3] = '4';
   printf("%s", *R1);
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is the difference between char s\[\] and char \*s in C?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1704407/what-is-the-difference-between-char-s-and-char-s-in-c)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should work for you:

```
#include <stdio.h>

char  R1[6] = "33333";

int main () {

    printf("%s\n", R1);
    R1[3] = '4';
    printf("%s", R1);

    return 0;

}
```

Output:

```
33333
33343
```

**EDIT:**

With a pointer this should work for you:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main () {

    char * R1 = malloc(6*sizeof(char));
    strcpy(R1, "33333");

    printf("%s\n", R1);
    R1[3] = '4';
    printf("%s", R1);

    free(R1);

    return 0;

}
```

Comment: @34hjjekjr: You can just take a pointer to the array if you don't want to/aren't allowed to use dynamic allocation.

Comment: Thanks, this works although I might have to change my actual program.

Answer (score 1):

Your code must be like this to get it work

```
char  R1[6]="33333";       
int main (){
   printf("%s\n", R1);
   R1[3] = '4';
   printf("%s", R1);
   return 0;
}
```

let's analyze your wrong code to figure out the problems

***first ERROR***

```
char * R1[6];
```

here you are declaring an array of 6 pointer pointing each one to a char  but you want an array of 6 char that's why it should be `char  R1[6];` to get what you want

***second ERROR***

```
   *R1 = "33333";
```

in C language you cannot assign a string by using the operator `=` . You have two choices either you initialize when declaring it like that `char R1[6] = "33333";` or you can use the
function `strcpy()` located in the `string.h` library and it wil be `strcpy(R1,"33333");`

***third ERROR:***

```
printf("%s\n", *R1);
```

when dereferencing a string in `printf()` you need to provide only the address of the first element of the string which is the name of the array `R1` that's why it should be like that 
the instruction

`printf("%s\n", R1);`

the same thing for the last `printf()`

Comment: @Meninx That info should be edited into your answer.

Answer (score 1):

The variable you are declaring is not a pointer; it is in fact an array of six char pointers (this is why `printf` fails). If you want to use a char array, simply write:

```
char R1[6];
```

If you want a char pointer, write:

```
char *R1;
```

And initialize it somehow (probably with `malloc`):

```
/*in main*/
R1 = malloc(6); /*six bytes for five chars +null terminator*/
```

Make sure to zero-terminate your string:

```
R1[5] = '\0';
```

Once you have a valid, mutable* char sequence, you can assign to individual chars much like you are already:

```
R1[3] = '4';
```

However, when it comes to assigning the whole string, you'll want to use the [strcpy](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strcpy/) function instead of the `=` operator:

```
/*R1 now contains the text "33333"*/
strcpy(R1, "33333");
```

*When you write `R1 = "33333"`, you are assigning to the *pointer* instead of to the text it points to. Since `"33333"` is immutable, you won't be able to assign to the values in your string when your string is a direct reference to it.

So the complete program might look like this:

```
char *R1;       
int main (){
   R1 = malloc(6);
   R1[5] = '\0';
   strcpy(R1, "33333");
   printf("%s\n", R1);
   R1[3] = '4';
   printf("%s", R1);
   free(R1);
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: @Meninx That's a matter of taste. The standard mandates that `sizeof(char) == 1` so it's perfectly safe to just use the number of bytes you want, but your way is also fine, if a little verbose. Strictly speaking, the "best" way to allocate would probably be `malloc(6*sizeof(*R1))`, which guarantees that the correct amount of memory is allocated even if we change the type of R1.